# Add Constraint to Paragraph Field

Tags: forms, paragraphs

I'm attempting to follow [this documentation](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/entity-validation-api/providing-a-custom-validation-constraint) to add a custom constraint to a field in a Paragraph but I'm having trouble actually accessing that field.

Currently I have `my_content_type` with `paragraph_field`. This field accepts a number of different paragraph types. I'd like to be able to add a constraint to a field on a specific paragraph type that could be added to that field.

I've tried using `hook_entity_bundle_field_info_alter`, `hook_form_alter`, and `hook_field_widget_form_alter` but am having trouble actually accessing the proper field.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

@Vecta I hope this help you

```
function MYMODULE_entity_bundle_field_info_alter(&$fields, \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeInterface $entity_type, $bundle) {
  //with a node
  if ($entity_type->id() === 'node') {
    if ($bundle == 'article') {
      if (isset($fields['title'])) {
        // change constraint id
        $fields['title']->addConstraint('UniqueCode', []);
      }
    }
  }
  //with a paragraph
  if ($entity_type->id() === 'paragraph') {
    // use the paragraph machine name 
    if ($bundle == 'paragraph_name') {
      if (isset($fields['field_name'])) {
        // change constraint id
        $fields['field_name']->addConstraint('ConstraintId', []);
      }
    }
  }
}
```